# Do scriptures say one mustn't lie their age to be less?

Tags: scripture, belief, age

Generally people tend to lie about their age, mostly telling the wrong numbers in smaller figures than the actual age.

Recently, I heard an elder saying that lying about age with smaller figure results one becoming 'alpa-âyu' (अल्प-आयु). They told that they heard at some satsanga.

**So, does this notion find a scriptural backing?**